# How to migrate InfoPath forms from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 Site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath, 2016, infopath-2013

I have a custom list in SP 2013 Publishing site and i created & published a new item InfoPath form to this list now i want to move this InfoPath form to SharePoint 2016 Publishing site.
Here i don't want to upgrade Sp2013 Content database but only InfoPath forms
I created a same custom list in SP 2016 Site also with same metadata & columns.

Answer (score 0):

There are two other ways to migrate a custom list with its InfoPath form from SharePoint Server 2013 to SharePoint Server 2016 if you don't want to use database-attach method.

Export the list to a .cmp file via Central Administration -> Backup and Restore -> Export a site or list -> Select the List and Specify the destination for the export package -> Click Start Export.
[image]
Then copy the .cmp file to your SharePoint 2016 server and run the below command on your SharePoint 2016 server.

```
Import-SPWeb <site collection url> -Path <the location of .cmp file>
```

The Fast and proper way to move a list is moving it with a third party tool like ShareGate and etc. The advantage with the third party tools is that they are very simple, and they work well.

Comment: http://www.sharepointjunkies.com/migrate-infopath-forms-sharepoint-2013-sharepoint-online/  I tried this solution and it worked for me.